# Проблемы с бд или что то в коде не то

Tags: python, база-данных, telegram-bot, telebot, sqlite

```
import random
from time import sleep
import sqlite3
from telebot import types
from telebot.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton

bot = telebot.TeleBot('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
conn = sqlite3.connect('base.db', check_same_thread=False)
cur = conn.cursor()


cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT, age INTEGER, balance INTEGER, car TEXT, house TEXT, level INTEGER, city TEXT, card INTEGER)""")
conn.commit()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    uid = message.from_user.id
    bot.send_message(uid, " Привет! Для регистрации напиши /register\n\nЕсли ты уже зарегистрирован, то, прописав /register\n\n❕ВСЕ ДАННЫЕ СОТРУТСЯ И ТЫ НАЧНЁШЬ ВСЕ ЗАНОВО❕")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['register'])
def city(message):
    uid = message.from_user.id
    gen = message.text
    bot.send_message(uid, " Введи свой город:")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, enter_to_db)


def enter_to_db(message):
    uid = message.from_user.id
    name = message.from_user.username
    cit = message.text
    card = random.randint(1000000000000000, 9999999999999999)
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO users (id, username, age, balance, car, house, level, city, card) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", (uid, name, 18, 10000, 'none', 'none', 1, cit, card))
    conn.commit()
    bot.send_message(uid, f"Данные успешно внесены в базу данных!\nЧтобы посмотреть свой профиль пропиши /me")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['me'])
def me(message):
    uid = message.from_user.id
    cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?""", (uid, ))
    results = cur.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        bot.send_message(uid, f"‍♂️ Твой профиль:\n\n ID: {uid}\n Баланс: /bank\n Автомобиль: {row[4]}\n Дом: {row[5]}\n Город: {row[7]}\n Возраст: {row[2]}\n⭐ Уровень: {row[6]}")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['bank'])
def bank(message):
    uid = message.from_user.id
    bot.send_message(uid, " <i>Входим в банк...</i>", parse_mode='HTML')
    sleep(2)
    bot.send_message(uid, " <i>Вводим пин-код...</i>", parse_mode='HTML')
    sleep(2)
    cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?""", (uid, ))
    results = cur.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        mark = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        key = KeyboardButton("Перевод по Sigma ID")
        key2 = KeyboardButton("Перевод по номеру карты")
        mark.add(key, key2)
        bot.send_message(uid, f" Сигма Банк\n\n Ваш Sigma ID: <code>{uid}</code>\n Номер карты: <code>{row[8]}</code>\n Ваш баланс: {row[3]}", reply_markup=mark, parse_mode='HTML')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_message(message):
    uid = message.from_user.id
    if message.text == 'Перевод по Sigma ID':
        bot.send_message(uid, ' Введите Sigma ID получателя и сумму\n<i>Например: "3756835681 10000"</i>', parse_mode='HTML')
        bot.send_message(uid, "⚠ Если вы укажите неправильно Sigma ID, то деньги вернуть не получится!")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, perevod)


def perevod(message):
    uid = message.from_user.id
    words = message.text.split()
    id_p = words[0]
    cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?""", (uid,))
    results = cur.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        row[3] - int(words[1])
        bot.send_message(uid, f"✅ Перевод успешно выполнен!\n\nСумма: {words[1]}\nПолучатель: {words[0]}")
        conn.commit()

    cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?""", (id_p,))
    results = cur.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        row[3] + int(words[1])
        conn.commit()

    if message.text == 'Перевод по номеру карты':
        bot.send_message(uid, ' Введите номер карты получателя и сумму\n<i>Например: "123456789098765 10000"</i>', parse_mode='HTML')
        bot.send_message(uid, "⚠ Если вы укажите неправильно номер карты, то деньги вернуть не получится!")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, perevod_card)


def perevod_card(message):
    uid = message.from_user.id
    words = message.text.split()
    id_p = words[0]
    cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?""", (uid,))
    results = cur.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        row[3] - int(words[1])
        bot.send_message(uid, f"✅ Перевод успешно выполнен!\n\nСумма: {words[1]}\nПолучатель: {words[0]}")

    cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?""", (id_p,))
    results = cur.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        row[3] + int(words[1])
        bot.send_message(id_p, f" Уведомление о поступлении денег\n\nСумма: {words[1]}\nОтправитель: {uid}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling()
```

Comment: Вопрос в чём заключается? Вы это читали : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-this-question-body-does-not-meet-our-quality-standar ?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.